# Switching app properties at runtime with app behind balancer

Tags: java, spring, nginx, load-balancing

We have a Spring web app which is behind nginx balancer. A need occurred to change some properties at runtime, preferrably without redeployment/restart.

However, a simple in-memory way like a controller which changes the value doesn't solve the problem because the balancer will send it to one specific server and others will have old property value.

This property change feature is a tool for support team and is not expected to be used often.

We came up with next ideas:

1. Controller + field in the database which holds actual value. However, in this case we will need to always query the DB for actual value.
2. Controller + curl script + list of actual servers, not the balancer. Will do the job, but very error-prone in future.
3. Forget the idea and just redeploy the app changing the properties file manually.

Maybe there's something else?

No code is available yet, it's more like a design question.

Comment: You can go with Option 1 and use Spring Caching to reduce the latency of getting the data from DB.

Comment: We decided to use a field in the DB for now. Interesting note about the RefreshScope, though! Thank you.